# Locked out of my locally hosted Drupal site

Tags: authentication-authorization, acquia-dev-desktop

I am running a local distribution of Drupal "commons" using Acquia Dev Desktop on a mac and somehow got locked out of my site. I saved my login info and am almost sure it's correct, but I'm still locked out.

Anyone know how I can remedy this situation?

Just for context, I am new to Drupal, so would need a detailed guideline for the fix.

Comment: You can either use the forgot password feature on the login form, or use Drush to get a login link or reset the password from command line.

Comment: A general piece of advice. Always give as much information as possible. You did pretty well, but often knowing the version of Drupal is essential. Probably not this time ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Acquia Dev Desktop on a Mac, you have access to the best Drupal tool - [Drush](http://www.drush.org/). In a terminal, navigate to the folder containing your Drupal website and run

```
drush uli
```

It will return a link to reset the password for user 1. The URL returned from the command will look something like

```
http://default/user/reset/1/[numbers]/[hash]/login
```

Paste that URL into your browser and replace "default" with the (local) domain name for your site. Good luck!